# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Tags: python, dht22

I have 3 DHT22 sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi. Two connected to 5V, 1 to 3.3V.
Initially this worked fine. Now, one of the scripts running one of the sensors gives me this error:

```
RuntimeError, trying again...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tempsensor.py", line 31, in <module>
    humidity = format(humidity,".2f")
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
Lost access to message queue
```

My code is as follows:

```
import adafruit_dht
from ISStreamer.Streamer import Streamer
import time
import board

SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME = "Bedroom"
BUCKET_NAME = "Room Temperatures/Humidity"
BUCKET_KEY = "dht22sensor"
ACCESS_KEY = ""
MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS = 60
METRIC_UNITS = True

dhtSensor = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)
streamer = Streamer(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY, access_key=ACCESS_KEY)

while True:
        try:
                humidity = dhtSensor.humidity
                temp_c = dhtSensor.temperature
        except RuntimeError:
                print("RuntimeError, trying again...")
                continue
                
        if METRIC_UNITS:
                streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(C)", temp_c)
        else:
                temp_f = format(temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, ".2f")
                streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(F)", temp_f)
        humidity = format(humidity,".2f")
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Humidity(%)", humidity)
        streamer.flush()
        time.sleep(60*MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS)
```

I don't understand the problem with line 31, as nothing has changed from the initial script and two other scripts. Any suggestions?

Comment: As in your original question this is OLD unsupported code.

Comment: The code I have in this post was my way around my original question. This code does work. Problem was with broken cable, failing the DHT22 to supply data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software is failing to read that sensor.  When that happens it is returning the special value `None`.

You need to check for the `None` value or find another way of dealing with the error condition.

Comment: Literally failing to read. Problem was with a broken connector cable.